# ReferenceError: react is not defined chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am taking one of grider course on react in udemy,along the line ,i encounter an error i couldn't fix ,pls look at the screen shot and tell me what to do .how do i fix this error.Here is the file in git hub https://github.com/ayeremascot/blogapp/tree/master/ReduxSimpleStarter-master
[my chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vUbj.png)

[my atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og6h0.png)

[atom 2nd picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDuD6.png)

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself instead of posting screenshots of your code.

Comment: The one thing that jumps out is `react.Component` - React is supposed to be uppercase... In general post your code here and not just screenshots...

Comment: @AndrewL and sakoBu here is a github link to the code ,please take a look .thanks https://github.com/ayeremascot/blogapp/tree/master/ReduxSimpleStarter-master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SakoBu mentioned in his comment, your issue is with this line:

`class GoodBye extends react.Component`

It needs to be capitalized as "React".

Comment: Thanks ,i made some progress ,browser now display the text "header" at http://localhost:8080 but i want it to display "header" and "Hello!" when i visit http://localhost:8080/Hello   ,i have push the new update to git ,please check it @Keith Brewster